# Installing SSRS 2008 with already EXISTING Sharepoint 2007 instace?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I must admit I have researched a bit but keep coming into a block I am not seeing mentioned when attempting to do this:

Install a NEW SSRS instance on a NEW machine of 2008 to working with an EXISTING sharepoint 2007 site.

1. I go through the install of SSRS 2008 SP1 on a VM of MS Server 2008 64 bit.
2. The install goes fine and has no errors, then you get to the menu option of install that states:

[Pic for choices](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7944039/pics/SSRS%20Config%20Options.jpg)

A. Install the Native Mode
B. Install the Sharepoint Mode
C. Insall, but do not configure.

1. I choose option B and install completes.
2. I go to the SSRS Config manager and attempt to go to the Web Service URL and it states a SharePoint Assembly is missing???

[Pic for Reference Assembly Error](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7944039/pics/Error%20Connecting%20to%20WebService%20URL.jpg)

My issues are that I have in the past on numerous occasions gotten a stand alone of SSRS 2008 with no issues.  I have not found anything yet that mentions installing SSRS with an existing Sharepoint site or when prompted by Sharepoint to provide the URL of the web service and have it work.  Do you need to install SharePoint on both this server and an existing server?  The problem is also that I am very ignorant of SharePoint but I understand SQL fairly well for SSRS and admin tasks.  I am not in direct control of the SharePoint server and the person keeps asking me for the Web Service URL, I give them the default, it fails.

Should I just tell him to create a directory on the SharePoint server to BE THE WEB SERVICE URL and then add a reference to that in the SSRS config manager?  Should I install some small amount of Sharepoint on this server?  I am at a loss as a lot of online step by step configs assume you are building both at time of install or on the same machine. Then they completely skip over steps of referencing the WEB Service URL which is integral for any deployment process.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint must be installed on all servers in the Farm, including the Report Server.  Within SharePoint Configuration you will setup Reporting Services and set the correct URL to the Report Server.

Comment: I did that but now I am stuck on the Web Url that gets created in SSRS.  I see that it says:

Comment: 'The Report server has encountered a configuration error.  If the report server is configured to use SharePoint integrated mode, verify that the server is joined to the SharePoint farm and that the service account has been granted access to the SharePoint farm.'                                            The problem is that the service account I am using is supposedly the master account used for the SharePoint so I am not getting what access issues it could have.  Everytime I go to the Sharepoint config to add the url I get a '401 Authentication error' issue.

Comment: Have you setup kerberos on the Report Server (and SharePoint box)?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806870.aspx

Comment: On vacation sorry for the delay.  I am not certain as I did not set up the Sharepoint portion I will ask the person that did.  Thanks.